# How to compare $e^{i \alpha n^\beta}$ and $\int_n^{n+1}e^{i \alpha x^\beta}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

I am solving an exercise in my textbook. After some steps, I need to compare $e^{i \alpha n^\beta}$ and $\int_n^{n+1}e^{i \alpha x^\beta}\, dx$, where $\alpha\neq 0,0<\beta<1$, in order to investigate the convergence property for some series. I hope I can get something like 
$$|e^{i \alpha n^\beta}-\int_{n}^{n+1}e^{i \alpha x^\beta}\, dx|\leq\quad \text{something related to }n^{\gamma},\gamma<0$$

But unlike real-valued function, I can't use monotonicity of the function to tell their relation. I also try to evaluate the integral by  $y=x^\beta$, and by integration by part, we have 
$$\begin{align}
\int_{n}^{n+1}e^{i \alpha x^\beta}\, dx&=\int_{n^\beta}^{(n+1)^\beta}e^{i \alpha y}\,\frac{1}{\beta}y^{\frac{1}{\beta}-1} dy\\&=e^{i \alpha y}\,y^{\frac{1}{\beta}}\bigg|_{n^\beta}^{(n+1)^\beta}-i \alpha\int_{n^\beta}^{(n+1)^\beta}e^{i \alpha y}\,y^{\frac{1}{\beta}} dy\\&=e^{i \alpha (n+1)^\beta}(n+1)-e^{i \alpha n^\beta}n-i \alpha\int_{n^\beta}^{(n+1)^\beta}e^{i \alpha y}\,y^{\frac{1}{\beta}} dy
\end{align}$$

But I don't know how to continue. Maybe I should compare with $\int_{n-1}^{n}e^{i \alpha x^\beta}\, dx$?

Comment: Would something like $$\frac{\alpha\beta}{2 n^{1-\beta}}$$ be sufficient? (I'm assuming $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ here.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, it is. May you elaborate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, we can estimate

\begin{align}
\left\lvert e^{i\alpha n^\beta} - \int_n^{n+1} e^{i\alpha x^\beta}\,dx\right\rvert
&\leqslant \int_n^{n+1} \left\lvert e^{i\alpha n^\beta} - e^{i\alpha x^\beta}\right\rvert\,dx \\
&= \int_n^{n+1} 2 \left\lvert \sin \frac{\alpha n^\beta - \alpha x^\beta}{2}\right\rvert\,dx\\
&\leqslant \lvert\alpha\rvert \int_n^{n+1} \lvert x^\beta - n^\beta\rvert\,dx\\
&= \lvert\alpha\rvert \int_n^{n+1} \beta\cdot (n+\xi(x))^{\beta-1}\cdot (x-n)\,dx\\
&\leqslant \frac{\lvert\alpha\rvert\beta}{n^{1-\beta}} \int_n^{n+1} (x-n)\,dx\\
&= \frac{\lvert\alpha\rvert\beta}{2n^{1-\beta}}
\end{align}

using $\lvert e^{ix}-e^{iy}\rvert = 2\left\lvert\sin \frac{x-y}{2}\right\rvert$, $\lvert \sin x\rvert \leqslant \lvert x\rvert$ for real $x$, and the mean value theorem.

Comment: The answer is very clear. Thank you.